# Create a global function like jest does

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, typescript-typings, typing

I am working on a meta framework that will use react.

I would like to offer some functions that are directly available without the need of an import, exactly like jest does with the function `it()`, `beforeAll()` etc...

[image: Global function without import when jest is in the project]

I basically succeed by simply declaring a typed var like this :

```
//myfile.d.ts
declare var someFunction : () =>  string
```

and then by assigning a function to it :

```
//someFile.ts
someFunction = () => "This is working"
```

Then, at the root of the project, I just imported once someFile.ts to make sure that **someFunction** was defined :

```
import "./someFile"
```

and yep, we are good, the function is global and does not require an import, and correctly typed !

[image: Global function without import working]

So , what is the problem ?

Well this work when I declare my type myself.
But if I need to use a library's type to create my own type, it does not work anymore

Let say I want to make the axios object available globally without the need to have an import.

So here is what I did in the declaration file

```
import { Axios } from "axios"
interface MyOwnAxiosType extends Axios {}

declare var myOwnAxios:MyOwnAxiosType
```

But as soon as the import is added at the top, the `myOwnAxios` is not found anymore outside of this file

[image: Global var not found when import added during the declaration]

If you have any idea of what I may be doing wrong, any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:
In a ts file

```
import * as axios_ from "axios"

declare global {
    var myOwnAxioss : typeof axios_.default
}
global.myOwnAxioss = axios_ as any
```

And that's it, you can now do this without any import, and with typings.

```
myOwnAxioss.get()
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `import` in your file makes your declaration file a module and not an ambient declaration context.

Instead you will have to use this confusing syntax:

```
import Axios = import("axios").Axios;

interface MyOwnAxiosType extends Axios {}

declare var myOwnAxios:MyOwnAxiosType
```

- `import("axios")` imports the module `axios` as a namespace (only types)
- `import("axios").Axios` gets the type `Axios` from the namespace
- `import Axios = import("axios").Axios` give the type above an alias

Using this kind of import will solve the issue because you are no longer using a static import.

---

If that doesn't work you can try inlining it:

```
interface MyOwnAxiosType extends import("axios").Axios {}

declare var myOwnAxios:MyOwnAxiosType
```

Comment: Does not seems valid js.
You can't write "import Axios =" also
import("axios") is a promise, so you can't do import("axios").Axios you have to do 
import("axios").then( ....

Comment: @Topsy This should be in a .d.ts file? In a regular TS file it of course will not work... Edited answer with alternative if it doesn't work.